# Cannot install Gnome- or Google chrome

Tags: installation, gnome, google-chrome

I just cannot install gnome-shell in my just installed 12.04 LTS

```
Message:
gnome-shell: Depends: libgjs0- but it is a virtual package
             Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.2 is to be installed
             Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.2 is to be installed
             Depends: libxfixes3 (>= 1:5.0) but 1:5.0-4ubuntu4 is to be installed
             Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.4.1-0ubuntu2) but 3.4.1-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

I cannot neither install Google Chrome

I am not very good in commands, I'm a normal user...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It looks like you've got a messed up repositories configuration with all kinds of releases mixed. Don't add random PPAs or add lines to sources.list if you don't know what you're doing. Could you include the output of `grep -vrE "(^#|^$)" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` run from the terminal? (edit your question)

Comment: You don't need to use the command line to install software, use the software centre. However this error will probably stop you installing there as well, try sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get install gnome-shell in a terminal and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

you can only get google chrome from here:
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the command line to install most applications.

As [Sean Fell](https://askubuntu.com/users/137247/sean-fell) already said, you should download Chrome from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/ .

If you want GNOME, you should use [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org) instead of Ubuntu.

Comment: Or he might want both, there's no point reinstalling his OS for the sake of changing DE.

Answer (score 0):

The GNOME Shell can be installed through the Ubuntu Software Center. As for Google Chrome you should visit their website [google.com/chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) and choose .deb package for you architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way of instating Chrome is:

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

If you already have Chrome installed follow this:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And then

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Comment: you might want to run `sudo apt-get update` first